# Can't remove blank select <option> created by ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a common problem however when trying to use the solutions provided here on Stackoverflow I am having no success... I have the following in my HTML view:

```
<select class="date-input" ng-model="reservation.date">
<option ng-repeat="d in dates track by $index"
        value="{{ d }}"
        > {{ d }} </option>
</select>
```

In my controller I have the following...

```
$scope.makeDates = (function () {
 dArray =[];
// we make a big array of dates ['dd-mm-yyyy','dd-mm-yyyy', 'dd-mm-yyyy'...] for 3 months and return it
 return dArray;
}();

$scope.reservation = { 
      date : null,
      time : null,
      quantity : null
};
$scope.dates = $scope.makeDates;
$scope.reservation.date = $scope.dates[0];
```

However despite me setting `$scope.reservation.date = $scope.dates[0];` the select still produces a blank option and is the default/selected value!?!?! Am I missing something? I know it is early but I can't see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use <select> with `ng-options`?

Comment: Thanks Miszy however later I may need to use ‘ng-selected‘ and this isn't supported with ‘ng-options‘... I also want to know why this is happening

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need attribute `value="{{ d }}"` for `<option>`. This is a reason why you get empty item.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <select class="date-input" ng-model="reservation.date">        
         <option ng-repeat="d in dates track by $index">{{d}}</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/53/)**</kbd>